# Check if an item is a specific ArrayList instead of one with equal values

Tags: java, arraylist

I have 3 ArrayLists initialized and then given integer values

```
ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> list3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list1.add(12);
list1.add(25);
list2.add(9);
list3.add(12);
list3.add(25);
```

I then pack them all into another ArrayList

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> lists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
lists.add(list1);
lists.add(list2);
lists.add(list3);
```

Now I want to iterate over the `lists` ArrayList to do some `if` statements

```
for (ArrayList<Integer> i : lists)
{
    ...
    if(i == list3)
    {
         i.add(10);
    }
    ...
}
```

But then I realize that the condition would be true for both `list1` and `list3` and execute the adding for both of them. When what I'm trying to do is for it to only trigger for `list3` specifically, not any list that happens to share the same values. In another words, a way to check for a specific item, now that I know that `==` wouldn't work.

Comment: You want reference equality, correct? Then `==` is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2):

The snippet you provided should be correct if you wish to test for equality against list3's reference.

The `==` operator tests for referential equality (i.e. `i == list3` tests whether i and list3 are the same object in memory), whereas the scenario you describe is only an issue when you use the `equals` method, which performs an element-wise comparison between the `ArrayList` objects.

Comment: Huh, this is so weird, I just copied the stuff I posted into the compiler and now it works. I probably made a mistake somewhere before. Thanks!